# Python Script not updating file contents while using a pyinstaller version of the script on a machine without python installed

Tags: python

So my issue right now is that I wrote a script that would update contents within a file each time you hit an arrow key.  The script works great on my PC.  I used pyinstaller in an attempt to create a straight forward standalone version of the script.  The problem right now is that the script is not seemingly updating their files!  Within the console of the application, it does show that it is properly counting up the scores, but upon opening the file it stays at 0!  Files are not in read-only.. any ideas?  Code below:

````
import os
import time
import threading


from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):

    if (key == keyboard.Key.down):
        wR = open("Round Number.txt", "w")
        w1 = open("Team 1 Score.txt", "w")
        w2 = open("Team 2 Score.txt", "w")
        wR.write("1")
        w1.write("0")
        w2.write("0")
        print("All values have been reset")
    
    if (key == keyboard.Key.up):
        r = open("Round Number.txt", "r")
        previousScore = r.read()
        w = open("Round Number.txt", "w")
        newScore = str(int(previousScore) + 1)
        print("Round file has changed to " + newScore)
        w.write(newScore)
        #print(open("Round Number", "r").read())
    
    if (key == keyboard.Key.left):
        r = open("Team 1 Score.txt", "r")
        previousScore = r.read()
        w = open("Team 1 Score.txt", "w")
        newScore = str(int(previousScore) + 10)
        w.write(newScore)
        print("Team 1 now has " + newScore)
        #print(open("Team 1 Score.txt", "r").read())

    if (key == keyboard.Key.right):
        r = open("Team 2 Score.txt", "r")
        previousScore = r.read()
        w = open("Team 2 Score.txt", "w")
        newScore = str(int(previousScore) + 10)
        w.write(newScore)
        print("Team 2 now has " + newScore)
       # print(open("Team 2 Score.txt", "r").read())

def on_release(key):
    pass
    #print('{0} released'.format(
        #key))
    '''if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False'''

#Collect events until released
with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()

# ...or, in a non-blocking fashion:
listener = keyboard.Listener(
    on_press=on_press,
    on_release=on_release)
listener.start()```
````

Comment: what command did you use while creating the executable? In particular, what flags?

Comment: just pyinstaller casting.py  ... another interesting symptom is i gave the person this instruction .... "something to check out.. this wont fix anything but may help me diagnose it.. but if you can at some point open the script.. hit down arrow to reset it to 0.... hit left twice to get team 1 to 20... then close the application.. re open it and hit left arrow.. Let me know if that goes to 30 or 10" and it went to 30.. so im feeling like it created a file somewhere.  But i dont get that behavior.. but its reading from SOMEWHERE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the main mistakes I immediately saw in your code was that you weren't closing the files once you were opening them. I hadn't tested your code directly but I did modify it to use `with` as below. I tested it and it is working fine. I also created an executable and that too is working fine with values being stored in the files.

```py
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):

    if (key == keyboard.Key.down):
        with open("Round Number.txt", "w") as wR:
            wR.write("1")
        with open("Team 1 Score.txt", "w") as w1:
            w1.write("0")       
        with open("Team 2 Score.txt", "w") as w2:
            w2.write("0")

        print("All values have been reset")

    if (key == keyboard.Key.up):
        with open("Round Number.txt", "r") as r:
            previousScore = r.read()
        with open("Round Number.txt", "w") as w:
            newScore = str(int(previousScore) + 1)
            w.write(newScore)

        print("Round file has changed to " + newScore)
    
    if (key == keyboard.Key.left):
        with open("Team 1 Score.txt", "r") as r:
            previousScore = r.read()
        with open("Team 1 Score.txt", "w") as w:
            newScore = str(int(previousScore) + 10)
            w.write(newScore)
        print("Team 1 now has " + newScore)

    if (key == keyboard.Key.right):
        with open("Team 2 Score.txt", "r") as r:
            previousScore = r.read()
        with open("Team 2 Score.txt", "w") as w:
            newScore = str(int(previousScore) + 10)
            w.write(newScore)
        print("Team 2 now has " + newScore)

def on_release(key):
    pass

#Collect events until released
with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press,on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()

# ...or, in a non-blocking fashion:
listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press,on_release=on_release)
listener.start()
```

One main problem though is that I had to manually create the 3 files and not pressing <kbd>Down</kbd> at the beginning caused the program to crash. Try resolving this too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  Seems there was some sort of antivirus on his computer the does containment and created another file in a "VTRoot" folder lol.. when he turned it off, it works perfectly.